# How to initialize a static const member of type depending on T in a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates

Given the following class

```
template <class T>
class A {
    static const B<T> member;
};
```

how can I instantiate `member` for each class `A<T>` separately?

Answer (score 6):

Simple. As you would with any other static non-integral type.

```
template <class T>
class A {
    static const B<T> member;
};


template <class T>
const B<T> A<T>::member/*(optional-args)*/;
```

In order to allocate member differently for different types of `T`, you must use [template specialisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c401y1kb(v=vs.80).aspx).

To start the template specialisation you must use this syntax:

```
template<>
// ... explicit definition
```

The syntax for the explicit definition is basically the same syntax as:

```
template <class T>
const B<T> A<T>::member/*(optional-args)*/;
```

Except, instead of `template <class T>`, you use `template<>`, and where `T` is, you put the actual type.

For example:

```
template<>
const B<type> A<type>::member(args);
```

**NOTE:** If you wish to call the default constructor with template specialisation in this scenario, please see the EDIT below.

You can substitute `type` for any type you wish. With this you can provide different arguments for each possible type. Although if you specialise too much, you should consider if your design is really suited to use templates.

[Here](http://ideone.com/GmGlbv) it is in action (online), feel free to clone and play around with it.

I thought I'd mention that the declaration must be where the template class is located. In other words, if `A` is declared in the header, you must also declare the allocation for `member` in the header file. You can alternatively use an inline file (.inl) and `#include` the .inl file in the header file that the template class is declared.

## EDIT:

It seems that in C++98, the following syntax to call the default constructor does not compile under GCC or clang, if you refer to the member variable:

```
 template <>
 const B<type> A<type>::member/*()*/;
```

Where type is any type.

However the following does:

```
 template <class T>
 const B<T> A<T>::member/*()*/;
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or just incorrect syntax.
I recommend instead to do the following:

```
 template <>
 const B<type> A<type>::member = B<type>();
```

Or if you are using C++11, you can use curly brackets to call the default-constructor, like so:

```
 template <>
 const B<type> A<type>::member{};
```

If you use regular brackets, the compiler will thing it is a static function within the `A<type>` class, and if you use no brackets, you will get an `undefined reference to 'A<type>::member'` linker error. Which you can see [here](http://ideone.com/j9xM0N).

[Here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8882945#8882945) is the discussion that Aaron and I discovered this error.

Comment: How can this be an instantiation if you haven't specified `T`? I want it to be possible to specify constant for each type `T` separately. I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: As in you want to use template specialisation?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I just didn't know what it was called.

Comment: Also, do you know how templates work? Once you create an object of ``A<T>``, where T is any type, the compiler will generate a duplicate class, by subsisting ``T`` with the type you specified. In other words, member will be allocated.

And I will edit my answer for template specialisation.

Comment: Yes, I know how templates work. Sorry if I initially didn't specify the question well enough.

Comment: How do I declare the allocation of `member`? I guess the definition `member` has to go in a .cpp file. By the way, doesn't the syntax `type symbol_name(/*optional arguments*/);` declare a function?

Comment: When you template specialise you can not put it inside a separate .cpp file, if your template class is in a header file. And that does not declare a function, it is quite an ambiguous statement, however the way I have used it will call the default constructor of ``B<int>``.

Comment: ``type symbol_name(/*optional arguments*/);`` is exactly the same as ``type symbol_name;`` as long as ``type symbol_name(/*optional arguments*/);`` was not declared in global scope or inside a class. If it was, then it would be a function (or member function). In C++11, if you used curly brackets, you would declare an object.

Comment: When I have the template specialisation in the header file, I get `multiple definitions of 'A<int>::member´` from the linker. Is the header file really the right place to define `member`? (By the way, how do you escape grave accents?)

Comment: Yes the header file is the right place. It is required, you must be doing something wrong. Join ##c++ on irc.freenode.net for help (I'll be in there too). And you two `'s not three.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28315/discussion-between-hellogoodbye-and-miguel-martin)

Comment: @miguel.martin, the ideone link is broken.